# vba assigning sub routine to variable

Tags: vba, variables, module, subroutine

I have the following sub routine (in module10).

```
Sub varWorksheet(wksht As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wksht)

Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to be able to pass this sub routine as a reference to a variable with something like this rather than have to declare it explicitly in each routine:

```
Set ws = module10.varWorksheet("Sheet1")
```

I'm getting a compilation error -> expected Function or Variable.

Comment: You cannot do that directly, there is no functional/delegate type in VBA (and if there were your attempt would be an invocation not an assignment).  Perhaps consider encapsulating the logic within a class http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use a function like this.

```
Function varWorksheet(wksht As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set varWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wksht)
End Function
```

It will return nothing if the worksheet doesn't exist. This works fine.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Modul10.varWorksheet("Tabelle4")
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No worksheet"
    Else
        ' what ever you want
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I prepared this, you went faster. Turning the sub into a function returning a worksheet object is the right thing to do

Comment: Thanks very much makes perfect sense.